# Does changing Exchange 2013 virtual directory authentication method effect Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

Does changing Exchange 2013 virtual directory authentication method effect Microsoft Outlook?

Our OWA authentication method is currently set to 'User name only' but we are going to change it to 'Domain\user name'.

In Microsoft Outlook, when users add their account they authenticate using their full e-mail address and password.

I assume that changing OWA to 'Domain\user name' won't effect that, as that's limited to the OWA virtual directory?

Answer (score 0):

The OWA virtual directory is unrelated to Outlook. Therefore changing the authentication system isn't going to have any effect.

However if you are using email address for authentication in Outlook, why not use that for OWA as well? Set it to UPN (which is what you are using for Outlook).

The only virtual directory authentication change that affects Outlook is Outlook Anywhere - even then it would be a change of authentication type, not whether it was username, domain/username or UPN. Furthermore a change would be picked up Outlook via Autodiscover.